# Unexpected highlighting in Sublime Text 3

Tags: ruby, sublimetext3

I've been using Sublime for quite some time.  I haven't done much customization, especially recently, however its highlighting lines of Ruby in a way I've never seen before.  I don't know where it came from or why its being highlighted.

Retyping the contents of a file into a new buffer and resaving does not solve the issue, the highlighting appears in the new file as well.

Has anyone seen this or have any pointers as to why its happening?

[image]

Full File Contents

```
require 'serialport'

port_str = '/dev/tty.usbmodemfd121'
baud_rate = 9600
data_bits = 8
stop_bits = 1
parity = SerialPort::None

sp = SerialPort.new(port_str, baud_rate, data_bits, stop_bits, parity)

while true do
  sp.puts 123
end

sp.close
```

Sublime Settings:

```
{
"alignment_chars":
[
    "="
],
"alignment_space_chars":
[
    "="
],
"font_size": 15.0,
"ignored_packages":
[
    "LiveReload",
    "Git",
    "_User",
    "SublimeLinter",
    "BracketHighlighter",
    "Rubocop"

],
"scroll_past_end": true
}
```

Ruby Specific Settings

```
{
  // The number of spaces a tab is considered equal to
  "tab_size": 2,

  // Set to true to insert spaces when tab is pressed
  "translate_tabs_to_spaces": true,

  // If translate_tabs_to_spaces is true, use_tab_stops will make tab and
  // backspace insert/delete up to the next tabstop
  "use_tab_stops": true,
}
```

Package Control Settings

```
{
"auto_upgrade_last_run": null,
"installed_packages":
[
    "AdvancedNewFile",
    "Alignment",
    "Better CoffeeScript",
    "BracketHighlighter",
    "CoffeeComplete Plus (Autocompletion)",
    "CoffeeScript",
    "DocBlockr",
    "Emmet",
    "Gist",
    "Git",
    "IndentGuides",
    "LiveReload",
    "Nettuts+ Fetch",
    "Package Control",
    "PhpBeautifier",
    "PlainTasks",
    "RSpec (snippets and syntax)",
    "RuboCop",
    "SCSS",
    "SublimeLinter",
    "Todo",
    "Wordpress"
]
}
```

Update: I think the issue is due to the RuboCop package. But its a little more complicated than that.

Currently Rubocop is enabled, I see highlighting and clicking on a highlighted line displays the offense in the bottom status bar as seen here.

[image]

However after disabling the Rubocop package and restarting Sublime there is still highlighting as shown here.  The lst shown at the top is the result from Sublime's "Package Control: Enable Package" command which means its showing the currently disabled package. Also, clicking on the highlighted line does not report the offense in the bottom status bar as before.

[image]

I'm feeling confident that the issue is the Rubocop package though I don't really have a diagnosis. I'm happy to close this question if necessary.

Comment: Ok, now append your image.

Comment: Hm, tried in Sublime Text 2 and had no unexpected highlighting...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was indeed an issue related to the Sublime RuboCop plugin.

The main error was, that the marks became invalid after restarting ST. Thanks @imbric for reporting it!

I fixed that today - if you update the plugin via Package Control, the unexpected marks should behave as expected.

You can turn off the marks via the ST menu entry "RuboCop: Toggle auto check".

Comment: The fix seems to work great. I didn't have to use Package Control to do an update since I think Sublime did one automatically for me at some point since the original post. (I'm on v2014.2.16.11.04.23)

Answer (score 0):

Part of the problem is also `BracketHighlighter`. I don't know Ruby that well, so I'm not sure why it's happening, but I get the following with BracketHighlighter (and a ton of other plugins) enabled:

[image: BracketHighlighter enabled]

When I disable BracketHighlighter, the question mark disappears, as does the box around the `while`. Try disabling BracketHighlighter, and see if your highlighting goes away.

Also, when I delete the word `do`, the box disappears, so it may just be a Ruby syntax error.

Comment: I'm not sure that's the problem I was seeing since BracketHighlight was always disabled.

Comment: @imbric did you try getting rid of the `do` after `while true` to see if the problem went away?

Comment: Yes, that is not a Rubocop offense and the issue remains. The issue here is related to highlighting remaining after the package is disabled, or not showing up when enabled.